# Displaying a hyphen"-" from a xml to Corona?

Tags: xml, lua, coronasdk

I have a xml file that has a hyphen"-" inside, how can I display the hyphen into the 
Corona apps?

Part of the xml file:

```
<data>Value : 54-57</data>
```

For now I can only display 5457 which became totally wrong.

Parts of the code for xmlparse:

```
print("found item")
if founditem == true then
    for i=1,#Item do 
        for j=1,#Item[i].child do
            if Item[i].child[j].name == "data" then
                DataReading[i] = simplifyData(Item[i].child[j].value)
            end
        end
    end 
end
```

Parts for the "SimplifyData" code:

```
function simplifyData(data)
data = string.gsub(data,"%a", "")
data = string.gsub(data,"%s","")
data = string.gsub(data,":","")
data = string.gsub(data,"-","")

data = tonumber(data)
return data 
end
```

Any ideas how can I make the hyphen display?
Thanks

**If I remove that line of code I would get an error**:

> attempt to compare nil with number

The error occurs in this part of the code :

```
function Datarating()
if DataReading[1] <= 50 then
    Results = "Pass"
elseif DataReading[1] <= 100 and DataReading[1] > 50 then
    Results = "Well Done"
elseif DataReading[1] <= 150 and DataReading[1] > 100 then
    Results = "Excellent"
          ...
          ...
          ...
else 
    Results = "Not Defined"
end
end
```

The line of errors is at :`if DataReading[1] <= 50 then`

Is there something wrong with the way I wrote my Datarating function?

---

```
function writeCurrentDataToLastUpdatedFile()
 print("writing current data to file")
 local path = system.pathForFile("filesupdate_data.txt",system.DocumentsDirectory)
 local file = io.open (path, "w")
 local currentDATA = DataReading[1]
 local printDataString = currentDATA
 file:write(printDataString) 
 print(printDataString)
 print("data written")
 io.close (file)
end
```

Comment: data = string.gsub(data,"-","") Aren't you removing hyphen here?

Comment: I had tried removing but it is causing me errors so I had to put that in to allow the program to run first.

Comment: Now you need to include the code where you define DataReading

Comment: Nope.. I typed wrong when posting. so it still does not work.

Comment: Tbh you need to rethink your code. First you take a value with hyphen, then you want to simplify it, why? Then you put it into your data-reading and try to compare '50' to '54-57' as if it was a simple number?

Comment: The problem is that I am unable to display the value with hyphen, If I do not simplify it, it would give another error: "attempt to compare string with number". Any idea how can I rework on the Datarating function? Allowing it to compare a range of values instead of a simple number? Once the "SimplifyData" function is removed, "DataReading[1]" became a string. So how should I compare string? Eg. 50-55 is considered "Pass" etc..

Comment: Look up how to split a string on a hypen, so you have two numbers. Then compare the highest of those two numbers.

Comment: The error says it all. You are comparing string '54-57' to 50. Which is similar to trying to compare "XYZ" to 50. Do as Frozire said - check if value has hyphen in it and do the splitting.